# Median Maintenance Algorithm - Same implementation yields different results depending on Int32 or Int64

Tags: c#, algorithm, integer, int64, int32

I found something interesting while doing a HW question.

The howework question asks to code the Median Maintenance algorithm.

The formal statement is as follows:

> The goal of this problem is to implement the "Median Maintenance" algorithm (covered in the Week 5 lecture on heap applications). The text file contains a list of the integers from 1 to 10000 in unsorted order; you should treat this as a stream of numbers, arriving one by one. Letting x<sub>i</sub> denote the i<sup>th</sup> number of the file, the k<sup>th</sup> median m<sub>k</sub> is defined as the median of the numbers x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>k</sub>. (So, if k is odd, then m<sub>k</sub> is ((k+1)/2)<sup>th</sup> smallest number among x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>k</sub>; if k is even, then m<sub>1</sub> is the (k/2)<sup>th</sup> smallest number among x<sub>1</sub>,…,x<sub>k</sub>.)

In order to get *O(n)* running time, this should be implemented using heaps obviously. Anyways, I coded this using Brute Force (deadline was too soon and needed an answer right away) (*O(n<sup>2</sup>*)) with the following steps:

1. Read data in
2. Sort array
3. Find Median
4. Add it to running time

I ran the algorithm through several test cases (with a known answer) and got the correct results, however when I was running the same algorithm on a larger data set I was getting the wrong answer. I was doing all the operations using Int64 ro represent the data. 
Then I tried switching to Int32 and magically I got the correct answer which makes no sense to me.

The code is below, and it is also found [here](https://github.com/lopezbertoni/AlgorithmsAnalysisAndDesign/blob/master/ProgrammingQuestion6/Program.cs) (the data is in the repo). The algorithm starts to give erroneous results after the 3810 index:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MedianMaintenance("Question2.txt");
    }

    private static void MedianMaintenance(string filename)
    {
        var txtData = File.ReadLines(filename).ToArray();
        var inputData32 = new List<Int32>();
        var medians32 = new List<Int32>();
        var sums32 = new List<Int32>();
        var inputData64 = new List<Int64>();
        var medians64 = new List<Int64>();
        var sums64 = new List<Int64>();
        var sum = 0;
        var sum64 = 0f;
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var s in txtData)
        {
            //Add to sorted list
            var intToAdd = Convert.ToInt32(s);

            inputData32.Add(intToAdd);
            inputData64.Add(Convert.ToInt64(s));

            //Compute sum
            var count = inputData32.Count;
            inputData32.Sort();
            inputData64.Sort();
            var index = 0;

            if (count%2 == 0)
            {
                //Even number of elements
                index = count/2 - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //Number is odd
                index = ((count + 1)/2) - 1;
            }
            var val32 = Convert.ToInt32(inputData32[index]);
            var val64 = Convert.ToInt64(inputData64[index]);
            if (i > 3810)
            {
                var t = sum;
                var t1 = sum + val32;
            }
            medians32.Add(val32);
            medians64.Add(val64);
            //Debug.WriteLine("Median is {0}", val);
            sum += val32;
            sums32.Add(Convert.ToInt32(sum));
            sum64 += val64;
            sums64.Add(Convert.ToInt64(sum64));
            i++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Median Maintenance result is {0}", (sum).ToString("N"));
        Console.WriteLine("Median Maintenance result is {0}", (medians32.Sum()).ToString("N"));

        Console.WriteLine("Median Maintenance result is {0} - Int64", (sum64).ToString("N"));
        Console.WriteLine("Median Maintenance result is {0} - Int64", (medians64.Sum()).ToString("N"));
    }
```

What's more interesting is that the running sum (in the sum64 variable) yields a different result than summing all items in the list with LINQ's Sum() function.

The results (the thirs one is the one that's wrong):
[image: Console Application Results]

These are the computer details:
[image: Computer details]

I'll appreciate if someone can give me some insights on why is this happening.

Thanks,

Comment: Despite the name, the `Convert` class is not a good way to convert data between known types.  Are you ever getting different results from `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToInt64`?  If you use `Int32.TryParse` and `Int64.TryParse` instead, do you get any failures?  Any differences then?

Comment: 0f is initializing a 32 bit float variable, you meant 0d or 0.0 to receive a 64 bit floating point.

Comment: @BenVoigt The results from the Convert.ToInt32/64 yield the same number, the sum is the one that's different. And I haven't tried to convert using TryParse yet.

Comment: @jtimperley: They shouldn't need a floating point at all. All the numbers are integers and so they should keep it all in intergers. They probably want `0L`, or else, just use explicit typing instead of `var`.

Comment: As for linq, you'll probably get better results if you use strongly typed lists. new List<int> and new List<long>.  To the last comment, they shouldn't need a bunch of this but I am not doing their homework, just pointing out their error.

Comment: @jtimperley you're correct, that's a bug in my code. Please post that as an answer and I will happily accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0f is initializing a 32 bit float variable, you meant 0d or 0.0 to receive a 64 bit floating point.

As for linq, you'll probably get better results if you use strongly typed lists.

```
new List<int>()
new List<long>()
```

Comment: Pretty sure they want `0L` or just `int64 sum64 = 0`. And they are using typed lists.

Comment: @matt-burland They had a floating point, I gave a floating point... Still not doing their homework.

Comment: @matt-burland Incorrect is relative, either data type will could produce the same result.  My answer is intentionally agnostic to intentions.  There is a huge difference between fixing an issue with someones solution and writing a better implementation.

Comment: I would hardly describe including such a minor detail as "writing a better implementation". If you insist on simply pointing out the problem and not helping with "homework", why suggest an alternate data type at all? I agree it's a bit misleading

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is what the commenter did: `var sum64 = 0f` initializes sum64 as a float. As the median value of a collection of Int64s will itself be an Int64 (the specified rules don't use the mean between two midpoint values in a collection of even cardinality), you should instead declare this variable explicitly as a `long`. In fact, I would go ahead and replace all usages of `var` in this code example; the convenience of `var` is being lost here in causing type-related bugs.

Comment: Understood, the problem was I was adding a float to a long. Any insights on why the sum starts to fail? Or is it just a precision error that gets carried over through the running sum?

Comment: If the numbers get big enough, definitely. Floating-point numbers have a fixed "significand"; only the first X binary digits can be accurately represented regardless of the magnitude of the number. So, at high enough values (for a "single-precision" float that's 24 bits or about 7 decimal digits), you'll start to see the least significant digits gets chopped off.